# "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function" Error

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a simple query to find any record where the field "peak_demand" is greater than 50.  For some reason, I'm getting the error mentioned in the title.  I have tried to read information about this error and they all seem to be related to character strings.  I do not have a LEFT or SUBSTRING function in my query.  Below is the text of my query.

```
select mm.fldmeterid "Meter#", dbo.fn_dt(dbo.fn_lt(rdv.sample_point,786)) "Read-Date-Time", mm.fldrepid , rdv.read_value_sum, peak_demand
from read_master_e rm
left outer join read_detail rd on rm.endpoint_id=rd.endpoint_id and rm.sample_point=rd.sample_point 
left outer join read_detail_value rdv on rdv.endpoint_id=rd.endpoint_id and rdv.sample_point=rd.sample_point 
left outer join tblmetermaint mm on (mm.FLDREPID= rm.endpoint_id)
where peak_demand > 50
order by rdv.sample_point desc
```

Comment: Have you looked into `fn_dt` and `fn_lt`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this query. As mentioned above error is from one of these scalar functions `fn_dt` and `fn_lt`

Comment: I had not, but I took out that part of the select statement entirely and I get the same error.

Comment: This might a great opportunity to turn those scalar functions into something that will provide better performance. Scalar functions are notoriously poor performers and when used as a column in a select like this they are a time bomb.

Comment: If you took out the UDFs, then narrow it down further: are any of the other objects Views and not Tables? If they're views, look at the code in the view for the LEFT or SUBSTRING functions.

Comment: Yes, the read_master_e table is actually a view.  I'm assuming that is what is causing my issue.  How can I see what is being selected in a View using Aqua Data Studio?  I've never had to do that.  Also, any idea why the query works when I change my "where" statement to something like "where mm.fldrepid = 45553676" ?